# roblox CFrame not working properly

Tags: roblox

So here is the code:

```
local prt = Instance.new('Part',game.Workspace)
prt.Color = Color3.new(248, 248, 248)
prt.Size = Vector3.new(0.167, 5, 5)
prt.Rotation = Vector3.new(0, 0, math.rad(90))
prt.Anchored = true
prt.CFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(19.1, 618.59, 116.85))
prt.Shape = "Cylinder"
```

what i want it to do is create a new part that is shaped like a cylinder, i want it to be a flat cylinder but it does the exact oppisite, it is standing up, i have tried many things.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The CFrame is setting the Rotation to 0,0,0. This is because you're doing CFrame.new() before prt.Rotation. If you did CFrame.new(Vector3.new(19.1,618.59,116.85)) * CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(90)), this would work and you can remove the "prt.Rotation" part.